# Problem to retrieve a value in the Json of Google Api with PHP (The Json is broken I do not understand why)

Tags: json

I'm having trouble getting a value.

I would like to recover the value "15 Place du Capitol, 3100 Toulouse, France";

I got these values ​​thanks to google API, however I get this array which strangely resembles Json but which looks badly formatted.

```
enter code here
$json = ($item->fieldvalues['23']);
$encode = json_encode($json, true);
var_dump($encode);
var_dump(json_decode($encode));
```

Result of var_dump($json);

/home/dimitri/Bureau/joomla_add/plugins/flexicontent_fields/add_to_calendar/tmpl/value_default_dropdown.php:10:
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'a:17:{s:12:"addr_display";s:44:"15 Place du Capitole, 31000 Toulouse, France";s:14:"addr_formatted";s:44:"15 Place du Capitole, 31000 Toulouse, France";s:5:"addr1";s:20:"15 Place du Capitole";s:4:"city";s:8:"Toulouse";s:3:"zip";s:5:"31000";s:3:"lat";s:10:"43.6046965";s:3:"lon";s:9:"1.4427146";s:3:"url";s:114:"https://maps.google.com/?q=15+Place+du+Capitole,+31000+Toulouse,+France&ftid=0x12aebb61f6837269:0xd08ef21a5141b92f";s:4:"zoom";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:0:"";s:5:"addr2";s:0:"";s:5:"addr3";s:0:"";s:5:"state"'... (length=628)

I tried to encode and decode, but necessarily it does not work since the format is not good.
- I use a Google map API development key.

Do you have an idea of ​​the procedure to follow? thank you in advance.
Dimitri.

Comment: Welcome to SO Dimitri! Please edit your question and share the test code and the result in a code block instead of sharing print screens. In this case the piece of code is super short and probably someone will spot the issue right away but in general sharing the code in the preformatted text form gives people a chance to debug your code and increases the chance to get the answer you are searching for.

Comment: Please post content of '$json'.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of my question, this is my very first, I take note of the implementation for the next ones :)

Comment: If someone encounters the same problem as me, it was simply a beginner's error, I did not know the serialze () and unserialize () functions of php.